# How do I upload an app to App Store Connect from Xcode if I don't have an iPhone?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

How do I upload an app to App Store Connect from Xcode if I don't have an iPhone?

- If I set the Target SDK to simulator in Unity, I cannot archive.
- If I set it to device SDK, I cannot build it because I do not have a provisioning profile. And I can't get a provisioning profile because I don't own an Apple device.

Comment: Haha, I feel you. You could either run it on a **Virtual Machine**, use a **Cloud Service** like [MacInCloud][1], build a **hackintosh** or **borrow a mac** from friends. 


  [1]: https://www.macincloud.com

Comment: while i had an iphone this is not enough to mark your code for use in the appstore, so i bought a 400 pound mac that met minimum requirements.  A hackintosh is a lot harder than it sounds, and apple would be very upset

Comment: @Alex Lushiku I have a mac, but not an iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first go to your apple developer account and generate a valid provisioning profile for your application.

As for how do that: https://hyperpad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204378199-Create-a-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile

After that, you must configure your profile in your application in the XCode (you do that by selecting the proper profiles that you created in the General tabs of your project), and set the device target to deploy as "Generic iOS Device".

Then you are ready to go in Product > Archive > Upload to Appstore.

Comment: Thank you so much. That link was exactly what I needed.